Is this static struct variable guaranteed to be zero initialized apart from the one field which isn't?
Inside a function, I have a static variable which is a struct, and only one of its fields are initialized:
void func() {
  static constexpr xcb_change_window_attributes_value_list_t root_mask {
    .event_mask = XCB_EVENT_MASK_ENTER_WINDOW | XCB_EVENT_MASK_LEAVE_WINDOW |
                  XCB_EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE |
                  XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY
  };
  
  // do something else
}

I would like to know if the struct is guaranteed to be zero initialized before the one field inside it is set, or would the only initialization happening be just on the single field? The struct has about 15 other members which I explicitly do not want to have any other values but their default.

First, this is not valid C++17 code.  Designated initializers didn't become standardized until C++20.  Second, they should be zeroed, the full process is describe quite well here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Per 3.6.2, all objects with static or thread-local storage duration will be zero initialized if not constant initialized.

@NathanOliver: That link claims fields without designated initializers will be default-initialized which is actually incorrect (as are many details on that website) -- by the spec, the initialization of such fields depends on the storage duration -- zero-initialized for static and thread-local, and default-initialized for automatic and dynamic storage duration.

@ChrisDodd Does it?  It has For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows: [...] Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list., i.e. foo = {} which is value initialization and zero for built in types.

@NathanOliver ok that's good to know. I was getting warnings from GCC, so I thought I'd ask. What would be the preferred way of initializing such a struct the way I mentioned? Is it not possible?

Without a [mre] I can't say why you are getting an error.  Do note that this is not legal until you use the -std=c++20 compiler flag.  Everything I've know and read tells me all other fields should be either value initialized or initialized with their member initializer.

@NathanOliver It's not an error. I said GCC was showing warnings. This is because I was compiling with -Wall. My other option would be to move the variable to the global scope, and do the initialization in another function. I wanted to know why GCC was giving warnings about "missing initializer for member"

@smac89 Error, warning, same difference.  Without an [mre] its tough to say why you are getting it.  I don't get it with this trivialized example: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86429ac76b38adc6

@NathanOliver that's because you compiled with -std=c++20. I think I have my answer now. Thanks

@smac89 Okay.  I was thrown off as I get main.cpp:12:74: warning: C++ designated initializers only available with '-std=c++20' or '-std=gnu++20' [-Wc++20-extensions] as the warning when using c++17 mode

@NathanOliver ah yes. the warning shows up when you add -Wextra. It seems to even still appear with -std=c++20

A better way I've discovered is to use a constexpr lambda (since C++17) function to create the variable:
void func() {
  static constexpr auto root_mask = []() constexpr {
    xcb_change_window_attributes_value_list_t mask{}; // initialize here
    mask.event_mask =
        XCB_EVENT_MASK_ENTER_WINDOW | XCB_EVENT_MASK_LEAVE_WINDOW |
        XCB_EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY;
    return mask;
  }();
  
  // do something else
}

This way, the struct is fully initialized to zero, and compiler doesn't complain.

Overcomplicating to satisfy the compiler might not be the best method of operation. It hurts readability, maintenance and more prone to errors.

@SomeWittyUsername I agree, but that's why we have the ability to leave comments. My previous solution which involved inserting compiler pragma directives, was definitely less readable than this. Until a better solution comes along, this one stays and comment will help future me understand what's going on
